# Errors occurred when having too much widget in one page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I got a rendering problem when running this page. When I started the page, it was working fine until I added more widgets, the problem seems to come from when I have too much widget in a page. I am trying to have the email textfield and a flatbutton together in one row so I covered the two widget with Row(). But then I received an error about the width of textfield so I made a column within the row, but still get errors. I wrapped everything in one container.I am new to flutter, here is my code and the error log.

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Profile Page'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    // initialValue: widget.customerInfo.firstName,
                    readOnly: _editText,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'First Name *',
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter your first name';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    controller: _firstnameController,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    // initialValue: widget.customerInfo.lastName,
                    readOnly: _editText,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Last Name *',
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter your last name';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    controller: _lastnameController,
                  ),
                  Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Column(children: [
                      new FlatButton(
                          onPressed: _toggleEditName,
                          child: new Text(_editText ? "Edit Name" : "Done")),
                      new FlatButton(
                          onPressed: (!_editText ? initState : null),
                          child: new Text('Cancel')),
                    ])
                  ]),
                  Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Column(children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        // initialValue: widget.customerInfo.email,
                        readOnly: _editText,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Email *',
                        ),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your email';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        controller: _emailController,
                      ),
                      new FlatButton(onPressed: (null), child: new Text('>')),
                    ])
                  ]),
                  Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Column(children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        // initialValue: widget.customerInfo.phoneNum,
                        readOnly: _editText,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Phone Number *',
                        ),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your phone number';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        controller: _phoneNumController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      ),
                      new FlatButton(onPressed: (null), child: new Text('>')),
                    ])
                  ])
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

```
I/flutter (18667): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (18667): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (18667): An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width.
I/flutter (18667): This happens when the parent widget does not provide a finite width constraint. For example, if the
I/flutter (18667): InputDecorator is contained by a Row, then its width must be constrained. An Expanded widget or a
I/flutter (18667): SizedBox can be used to constrain the width of the InputDecorator or the TextField that contains it.
I/flutter (18667): 'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart':
I/flutter (18667): Failed assertion: line 910 pos 7: 'layoutConstraints.maxWidth < double.infinity'
I/flutter (18667):
I/flutter (18667): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (18667): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (18667): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (18667):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter (18667):
I/flutter (18667): Widget creation tracking is currently disabled. Enabling it enables improved error messages. It can
I/flutter (18667): be enabled by passing `--track-widget-creation` to `flutter run` or `flutter test`.
I/flutter (18667):
I/flutter (18667): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (18667): #2      _RenderDecoration._layout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:910:7)
I/flutter (18667): #3      _RenderDecoration.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1214:44)
I/flutter (18667): #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #13     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:744:15)
I/flutter (18667): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #15     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:744:15)
I/flutter (18667): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #17     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:744:15)
I/flutter (18667): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #19     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:392:13)
I/flutter (18667): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #21     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter (18667): #22     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:444:7)
I/flutter (18667): #23     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter (18667): #24     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter (18667): #25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #29     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1232:11)
I/flutter (18667): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #31     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #43     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #46     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3140:13)
I/flutter (18667): #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #48     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter (18667): #49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #56     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #60     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (18667): #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (18667): #62     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:152:13)
I/flutter (18667): #63     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1578:7)
I/flutter (18667): #64     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:844:18)
I/flutter (18667): #65     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:341:19)
I/flutter (18667): #66     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:761:13)
I/flutter (18667): #67     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:280:5)
I/flutter (18667): #68     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1033:15)
I/flutter (18667): #69     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:975:9)
I/flutter (18667): #70     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:784:7)
I/flutter (18667): #72     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter (18667): #73     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter (18667): #74     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
I/flutter (18667): (elided 3 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async-patch)
I/flutter (18667):
I/flutter (18667): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: _RenderDecoration#ca773 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
I/flutter (18667):   needs compositing
I/flutter (18667):   creator: _Decorator ← InputDecorator ← AnimatedBuilder ← _PointerListener ← Listener ←
I/flutter (18667):     RawGestureDetector ← TextSelectionGestureDetector ← IgnorePointer ← MouseRegion ← Semantics ←
I/flutter (18667):     TextField ← TextFormField ← ⋯
I/flutter (18667):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter (18667):   constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
I/flutter (18667):   size: MISSING
I/flutter (18667): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter (18667):     input: RenderRepaintBoundary#b5169 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667):       child: RenderRepaintBoundary#9b420 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667):         child: RenderCustomPaint#5923d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667):           child: RenderRepaintBoundary#18532 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667):             child: RenderPointerListener#1ff64 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667):     label: RenderTransform#b9bc3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667):       child: RenderAnimatedOpacity#67b74 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667):         child: RenderParagraph#2d556 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667):           text: TextSpan
I/flutter (18667):     helperError: RenderConstrainedBox#e5505 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667):     container: RenderCustomPaint#333c9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (18667): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderDecoration#ca773 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#87013 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#25faf relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderMouseRegion#de7bf relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#7d5d1 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#9ae89 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#13e43 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (18667): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 321 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (18667): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '>' was called on null.
Reloaded 0 of 582 libraries in 330ms.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `column` which is inside the `row` must have a width, wrap it inside a `container`

```
  Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                // initialValue: widget.customerInfo.email,
                readOnly: _editText,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Email *',
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your email';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                controller: _emailController,
              ),
              new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (null), child: new Text('>')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```